# Create Slack Workspaces via API?

Tags: slack-api

We are a slack partner that could create a number of workspaces.  I was wondering if there was a way to create workspaces programatically.  Once created, we could use the api's to create channels, etc...what was wondering about the workspace creation.  Thanks!

Comment: I think this question should be directed to the Slack team. If Slack has a partner program there may be some special APIs for that.

Answer (score 1):

An year old post, but still thought of answering.
check for Slack Admin API... this need to be at org level.

https://api.slack.com/methods

admin.teams.create

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API for Workspace creation.